Can a law enforcement officer's testimony be hearsay?
Let's say a sheriff's deputy interviews a witness and on the basis of the information in that interview issues a citation for a statewide misdemeanor to Individual A. The witness's account is not written down by the deputy. Can that deputy testify in court (district or a court of limited jurisdiction) where the Individual A is on trial as to what the witness said? Or is that deputy's testimony hearsay?
As an aside: is a law enforcement officer's testimony in court automatically and legally deemed more reliable and give more legal weight than a sworn civilian witness or the defendant? I know a judge or a jury can assess testimony and decide who they believe; but does law enforcement testimony have more default legal weight?

Hearsay is a statement introduced into court, that an individual said out of court, if that statement is used for the purpose of showing the truth of its contents.
In Canada, see generally R. v. Khelawon, 2006 SCC 57 at para 35. In the US, see Federal Rules of Evidence 801 (technically only applicable in federal courts, but reflects the essentially universally accepted definition of hearsay):

“Hearsay” means a statement that:
(1) the declarant does not make while testifying at the current trial or hearing; and
(2) a party offers in evidence to prove the truth of the matter asserted in the statement.

So, it will depend on why the deputy is telling the court that the out-of-court witness said X.

If the purpose was, for example, to establish the reasonableness of the deputy's suspicion for a search or arrest, then it will not be hearsay. What matters in that case is merely that fact the deputy was told X, not that X is true.

If instead, X was introduced for the purpose of proving the crime, then that would be clearly be using X for the truth of its contents, and it would be treated as hearsay.



No witness has any "default" weight (although expert witnesses have a different scope of permissible evidence). Every witness is judged independently. It would be an error of law, reversible on appeal, if a judge revealed that they gave a category of person more "default legal weight" or if they instructed the jury to do so. Certain practices and experience can lead to more credibility and reliability: contemporaneous note-taking, a familiarity with a given scene, etc., but not the identity of the witness.

Thanks! I didn't think of the difference in order for a search or arrest.

Would there be any difference if the scenario was a he said / she said type scenario?
Where a witness claims to have seen a crime. The alleged criminal says that they did not. Ignoring other evidence for now. How would this one testimony be received if the witness was a law enforcement officer vs if they were a civilian? Would the law enforcement officer be treated as a more trustworthy source because of their profession?

I'd assume that this kind of witness testimony would not be a decider in any way. It might be supported by evidence, but that evidence could just be circumstantial and not actually prove that a crime took place. Would the weight of a cop be enough to tip the scales on circumstantial evidence? More than a civilian at least?

@TheEvilMetal That's basically asking the question on who to believe more if they provide opposing facts. That's the ultimate thing the judge or jury has to decide. The profession of a witness might be one element in deciding about the credibility.

@TheEvilMetal the law officer's testimony in this case isn't "I saw the defendant do X" but "I interviewed a witness who told me that they saw the defendant do X."  If there's no other evidence then the case will be dismissed or disposed by summary judgment; the defendant will not have to present any evidence or testimony.  A case where there is a witness who testifies in court that they saw the defendant do X is a distinct question from this one; it doesn't have anything to do with hearsay and should be asked as a new question (unless it has already been asked, which is likely).

@TheEvilMetal "Would the law enforcement officer be treated as a more trustworthy source because of their profession?": That often happens, but ultimately it's for the jury (or judge if there's no jury) to decide who's credible or not.  The impact of the witness's being a law enforcement officer will be different for different individuals.

@TheEvilMetal in the US, at least, there's a tradition of prosecutors presenting police officers as more reliable because of their training and more honorable because of their sworn oath of public service, but there is also awareness, perhaps increasing awareness in recent decades, that police officers can be corrupt and dishonorable.

@TheEvilMetal almost all evidence is circumstantial. Evidence of video, audio, or photographs showing the actual crime in all all its glory is pretty rare.

So far the sentiment that I am getting is that it shouldn't matter if the witness is a cop. But it probably will. Which is exactly the problem that this question is hinting at I think.

As something of a historical footnote, the hearsay rule was basically invented to prevent trials by affidavit or by recitation of what a lot of different people said by a law enforcement officer.

I was trying to google the relationship between hearsay and perjury cases, but it was complicated by the fact that perjury is often mentioned along with hearsay in other contexts.
